# Base64 encode png buffer using node-gd

Tags: javascript, node.js, png, gd

I'm trying to do some basic PNG manipulation using the [node-gd](https://github.com/y-a-v-a/node-gd) GD wrapper.

I'd like to:

- Open a png image
- Merge this png with an overlay png
- Encode the merged result buffer as a base64 string

My test code:

```
gd.openPng('./my_image.png', function(err, img) {
    img.saveAlpha(1);
    gd.openPng('./my_overlay.png', function(err, overlay) {
        overlay.copy(img, 0, 0, 0, 0, overlay.width, overlay.height);

        let buff = gd.createFromPngPtr(new Buffer(img.pngPtr())); /* this returns null? */
        console.log(buff); /* prints null as per previous line */

        let b64 = buff.toString('base64'); /* error: Cannot read property 'toString' of null */
        console.log(b64);        
    }); 
});
```

Why am I getting a null return on the `gd.createFromPngPtr` call?

Answer (score 1):

Solved like so:

```
gd.openPng('./di.png', function(err, img) {
    img.saveAlpha(1);
    gd.openPng('./flaming.png', function(err, overlay) {
        overlay.copy(img, 0, 0, 0, 0, overlay.width, overlay.height);
        var buff = Buffer.from(img.pngPtr(), 'binary');//, 'latin1');
        var b64 = buff.toString('base64');
        console.log(b64);
    }); 
});
```